# What's the meaning of "present" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the definition of *report* from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/report):

> 2 [transitive, intransitive] to present a written or spoken account of an event in a newspaper, on television, etc
>   - *The stabbing was reported in the local press.*
>   - *It was reported that several people had been arrested.*
>   - *The TV news reported that several people had been arrested.*
>   - *She reports on royal stories for the BBC.*

What does *present* mean in the above definition of *report*? From the same dictionary, there are several definitions of *present* that seems to fit the context, but I'm unsure which one is the most appropriate, they are:

> 2 to show or offer something for other people to look at or consider
>
> *The committee will present its final report to Parliament in June.*
>   *Eight options were presented for consideration.*
>   *Are you presenting a paper at the conference?*
>   *He presents a convincing case.*
>   *The banks will begin to present their arguments today.*
>
> 3 to show or describe something/somebody in a particular way
>
> *The company has decided it must present a more modern image.*
>   *It is essential that we present a united front*
>   *You need to present yourself better.*
>   *He likes to present himself as a radical politician.*
>   *The press presents this as a kind of victory.*
>   *The article presents these proposals as misguided.*

Definitions #6 and #7 below states that it only applies to television programmes/broadcasts, but not newspapers as it is included in the original definition of *report*?

> 6 to appear in a radio or television programme and introduce the different items in it
>
> *She used to present a gardening programme on TV.*
>
> 7 to produce a show, play, broadcast, etc. for the public
>
> *Compass Theatre Company presents a new production of ‘King Lear’.*
>   *The string orchestra of the Music School of Lemgo will present a concert in the Guildhall.*
>
> 10 present something (to somebody) (formal) to offer or express something in speech or writing
>
> *Please allow me to present my apologies.*

Comment: Neither word is specific to a medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those definitions are very similar. In general to "present" something is to offer it for others to read, hear, watch, or otherwise perceive. All the different definitions you give appear to be just shades of different meaning of that idea. It's not always possible to pick one dictionary definition to match a particular usage. Unless it's a class assignment to say which of these applies, I wouldn't worry about it as long as you get the idea. If you really need to pick one, I'd say #2 is closest.